# How to redirect all to ssl and to index.php but not ssl but redirect all to index.php on a specific page

Tags: php, apache

I want all to force redirect to https but not on a specific page currently i have this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I want all to redirect to https but force http on a specific page:
/exchage

What code do I need to put on my .htaccess file to achieve this function? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about adding another condition to the HTTPS redirect to check that the path doesn't start with `exchange`? (I assume you misspelled exch**age**)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/exchange
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/exchange
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Once you have updated your .htaccess file, please restart your browser. Otherwise it might force https if it has previously seen the URL use https.

Comment: exchange page still goes to https. :(

Comment: Updated again.. please try.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem with this code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/exchange
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /exchange
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

took me almost 3 hours just to come out with this code.

Comment: Cool that this works for you. Just note: This will trigger the http/https rule if the URL _contains_ `/exchange`... e.g. `/anything/exchange/whatever/` will also be forced to http.